# Setting up Traefik with LE integration - error too many redirects / 302

Tags: http, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik, http-status-code-302

I've been following the examples for Traefik and LE integration and those on SmartHomeBeginner, though I've been unable to get Traefik to work on the subdomain over https. I can see the backend on the IP address with the port number but that's not ideal.

When I view the HTTPS page in the browser I keep getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and I've confirmed the fail in Linux doing a simple wget and I get a 302 error and major fail after 20 redirects.

I can't see where I'm going wrong...

```
####### Docker Compose ##########
version: "3.6"
services:
  traefik:
     image: traefik:1.7.4
     container_name: traefik
     command: --api --docker
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 80:80
       - 443:443
     environment:
       - CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
       - CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
     networks:
       - traefik_proxy
     labels:
       - "traefik.enable=true"
       - "traefik.backend=traefik"
       - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}" 
       - "traefik.port=8080"
     volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
       - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
       - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/acme/acme.json:/acme.json
       - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared

###### traefik.toml ######

logLevel = "DEBUG" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC

defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "email"
storage = "/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
# remove below line when happy its all working fine - dev LE certs
caServer="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

#create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
   provider = "cloudflare"
   delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "xxxx.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.xxxx.com"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `When I view the HTTPS page` what page that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work out what I was missing, the traefik.toml and docker-compose file were both ok, the only issue was that Cloudflare was set to 'Flexible' but must be set as 'Off' as am trying to utilise the LE certs instead, this then worked. See link for reference: [s3 and cloudflare flexible ssl handshakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645907/s3-and-cloudflare-flexible-ssl-handshakes)